# Showing that $-\frac{1}{2}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n}\sin(n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

So I've been trying to prove that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n}\sin(n)}{n}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

I've tried putting various bounds on it to see if I can "squeeze" out the result. Say something like (one of many tried examples):
$$ -\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\leq \sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k}\sin(k)}{k}\leq \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}$$

I've tried too see if I could find some periodic continuous function in order to use Parseval's theorem, but I can't come up with any that work.

May I please get a hint or some piece of the puzzle for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guide:

Verify by computing the fourier series of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\pi}, -\pi < x<\pi$

$$\frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx)$$

and choose an appropriate value of $x$.

Comment: Is there a process for choosing that function? Is it something you just get intuition for? Or is there an obvious reason to choose that function?

Comment: hmmm... unfortunately for my case, it's something that I already know.

Answer (score 4):

A direct approach:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin n}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\Im (e^{in})}n=-\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(e^i)^n}n=-\Im\ln(1+e^i)$$
where the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+z)$ was used. As can be seen by drawing a diagram, $\arg(1+e^i)=\frac12$. This is thus the imaginary part of the logarithm, and thus the original sum is $-\frac12$.

Comment: The series converges for $ |z| < 1$. Why does it converge for $z=e^i$, which has absolute value $1$?

Comment: @lhf you can show that on the boundary the series converges except at $z=-1$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel One can show this using summation by parts, or more generally by appealing to Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 3):

Its is also possible to calculate the series above using the residue theorem from complex analysis. It goes as follows:$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty \text{Res}\left(\pi\csc(\pi z)\cdot\frac {\sin(z)}z,n\right)=-\text{Res}\left(\pi\csc(\pi z)\cdot\frac {\sin(z)}z,0\right)$$

The LHS becomes: 
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty\lim_{z\to n}\left[\pi  (z-n)\csc(\pi z)\cdot\frac {\sin(z)}z\right]=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {\sin(n)}n=2\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {\sin(n)}n$$

The RHS becomes: $$\lim_{z\to 0}\left[\pi z\csc(\pi z)\cdot\frac {\sin(z)}z\right]=1$$
Putting all together (LHS $=-$ RHS) you get: $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {\sin(n)}n=-\frac 12$$